# AJAX response not displaying the text

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Im a beginner with php and Javascript. I am trying to make an Ajax request using a JavaScript function to display the country description based on the form text input(country name). The response should come from a .php file which takes in country name as a parameter and produce a response that will consist of a brief description of that country when the user clicks the button. Below is my html code:

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
/
 var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {
 XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
 }
 else if (window.ActiveXObject)
 {
 XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
 }
 
 function getData(dataSource, divID)
 {
  if(XMLHttpRequestObject)
  {
  var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
  obj.innerHTML ="";
  XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);
  XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
  XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange =
  function()
   {
   if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
   XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
   {
    obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
   }
   }
  XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
  }
 }

</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1 align="center">Country Description</h1>

<form>
<p>Country Name: <input type="text" name="country">
<input type="button" value="Show Description" onclick="getData('hw5a.php', 'targetDiv')">
</p>
</form>
<div id="targetDiv">
<p>The response will display here</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Following is my php code:

```js
<?php
header("Cache-Control: post-check=1,pre-check=2");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

$c = $_GET['country'];
$c = strtolower($country);
echo $country;
if($c = 'canada')
{
echo '<p>canada</p>';
}
elseif($c = 'usa')
{
echo '<p>USA</p>';
}
elseif($c = 'mexico')
{
echo '<p>c</p>';
}
else 
echo '<p>Please check your spellings</p>'
?>
```

I am not sure what am i doing wrong. Any help or direction will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Inspect the console to see what data is being passed / retrieved. Use `console.log` to write to the console in your Javascript so you can debug which lines are being executed (or use `alert` if you prefer). Write back on what lines are not executing when they should, and whether or not you are getting any response at all.

Comment: there is variable called `$country` and you used `$c`

Comment: that was just left there when i was posting. Initially $c was $country but i changed it.

Answer (score 0):

First you should use `==` or `===` operator in php and you should test your `$_GET` variable if exist with `isset($_GET['country'])` since the variable might not exist and it's recommended for security reasons like SQL Injection.

In your HTML file, If you don't want to load the page then you can use XHR specifying Your URL `hw5a.php?country=`, but you must send with it the value of the country like this `hw5a.php?country=canada`.

Try this one, your php file should look like

```
    <?php
header("Cache-Control: post-check=1,pre-check=2");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

if(isset($_GET['country'])){

$country = $_GET['country'];
$country = strtolower($country);

if($country === 'canada')
{
echo '<p>canada</p>';
}
elseif($country === 'usa')
{
echo '<p>USA</p>';
}
elseif($country === 'mexico')
{
echo '<p>mexico</p>';
}
else 
echo '<p>Please check your spellings</p>';
}

?>
```

Your HTML

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script>
    var XMLHttpRequestObject = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
      XMLHttpRequestObject = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
      XMLHttpRequestObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    function getData(divID) {
      //Define Your URL
      var dataSource = "hw5a.php?country=" + document.querySelector('#countryInput').value;
      if (XMLHttpRequestObject) {

        var obj = document.getElementById(divID);
        obj.innerHTML = "";
        XMLHttpRequestObject.open("GET", dataSource);
        XMLHttpRequestObject.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',
          'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange =
          function() {
            if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&
              XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200) {
              console.log(XMLHttpRequestObject);
              obj.innerHTML = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseText;
            }
          }
        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <h1 align="center">Country Description</h1>

  <form>
    <p>Country Name: <input id="countryInput" type="text" name="country">
      <input type="button" value="Show Description" onclick="getData('targetDiv')">
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="targetDiv">
    <p>The response will display here</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```